# Need help in usage of Login volume with iscsi

Tags: iscsi

Need a command line argument to login the volume with persistent login i tried with follwing command. but not working.
iscsicli persistentlogintarget iqn.2003-10.com.lefthandnetworks:mg-test:51:volume " T * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 0"

Please help
Regards
NewDev

Answer (score 0):

cmd>iscsicli persistentlogintarget 
              TargetName T * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 0

The output was:

Microsoft iSCSI Initiator Version 6.0 Build 6000

The operation completed successfully.

To confirm that the operation was successful, I entered:

cmd>iscsicli listpersistenttargets

Id it doesnt list the targets then there is some problem.Try qlogintarget to check if it is succesfull.

Comment: try providing the ipaddress in the target name

Comment: please format your code as `code` otherwise it's super difficult to read.